# Changing styles of angular material snack-bar after interval

Tags: angular, angular-material, snackbar

I have created a custom angular material snackbar and I would like to change it's background colour after a time interval (before it closes). So far I have tried the following code, but the background colour does not change as expected. I am new to Angular...any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

```
openSnackBar(isLoading: boolean = true) { 
  this._snackBar.openFromComponent(SnackbarComponent, {
      duration: 5000,
      panelClass: isLoading ? "greenClass" : "blueClass",
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    isLoading = false;
  }, 2000);
}
```

I tried to put the setTimeout function inside the ngOnInit() but I was getting an error: `Property 'isLoading' does not exist on type 'SnackbarButtonComponent'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your code is that Property 'isLoading' is not property of snakebar(which directly opens in dom).

You can achive this by using dom query selector

```
openSnackBar() {
    this._snackBar.openFromComponent(SnackbarComponent, {
      duration: 5000,
      panelClass: ['panelClass'],
    });
    setTimeout(() => {

       let mysnackbar: any = document.querySelectorAll('.panelClass')[0]; // querying out our panelClass
       mysnackbar.style.cssText += 'background-color: #9b8b8b !important'; // changing value
   
    }, 2000);
  }
```

remember to add panelClass in your global styles(styles.css file).

```
.panelClass {
  background-color: pink; // initial background color
}
```

i have created a stackblitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o34a34-a6kcsk?file=src/app/snack-bar-component-example.ts)